# Powerbuilder application crashes on citrix environment

Tags: citrix, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I am new to citrix env.

When i run a PB application on Citrix environment, for a particular screen PB appl gets crashed without any error for the particulat screen. If I check the same in PB spource it is working fine. I dont know why it is happening.

Can you help me?

Comment: did you mean 'PB source' instead of spource?

Answer (score 0):

The multi-monitor hooks are the most common cause of unexpected behaviour on Citrix servers. So try adding an exception into the registry for your application to disable Citrix multi-monitor hooking to see if that helps. The following article describes how to do this:

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX129712

Edit: for further ideas.

If disabling the MM hooks doesn't help, the only other thing I can think of is to check what DLLs are loaded in the process when it crashes. Check the stack dump you get from your crash and look at all the loaded DLLs, e.g. using Windbg to inspect your dump you can use the following commands:

http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#10_modules

Look for any Citrix DLLs loaded in the process space. You can then look for those files in the file system and temporarily rename them to hide them (so they won't get loaded into your process). Note: most Citrix DLLs live in C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\system32.

If that doesn't help all I can suggest is putting debugging tools on a Citrix server and debugging the app.